# How To Export All Store Procedures Code Definition Along With SP Name in SQL Server2000?

Tags: sql-server

I am using SQL Server2000 database.

I need to export all store procedures code i.e. code definition (and not the result) with store procedure names in text file format or it could be fine in excel file format also.

I googled but most of the topics were on how to export the SP output. I need to export SP definition with SP name.

Since I have not used SQL Server database, so could not point out how to do this.

Could you please guide me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- you can use enterprise manager and the scripting wizard to script the text either into individual files or all stored procedures in one big file and then print them out!

if you right click on the database - go to "all tasks" - generate sql scripts - you can then enter your specs in each tab...under the options tab you can check either the "create one file" or "create one file per object"!

OR

- You can change settings from SSMS: Options>>Query Results>>SQL Server >>General>> you have three options here to save result: Results to grid;Results to text; Result to file.